# Count the number of strings with length in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, count

I am trying to calculate the number of strings in a column with length of 5 or more. These strings are in a column separated by comma.

```
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['first'])
df['first'] = ['Jack Ryan, Tom O','Stack Over Flow, StackOverFlow','Jurassic Park, IT', 'GOT']
```

Code I have used till now but not creating a new column with counts of strings of more than 5 characters.

```
df['countStrings'] = df['first'].str.split(',').count(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}')
```

Expected Output: Counting Strings of length 5 or More.

| first | countString |
| --- | --- |
| Jack Ryan, Tom O | 0 |
| Stack Over Flow, StackOverFlow | 2 |
| Jurassic Park, IT | 1 |
| GOT | 0 |

Edge Case: Strings of length more than 5 separated by comma and have multiple spaces

| first | wrongCounts | rightCounts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Accounts Payable Goods for Resale | 4 | 1 |
| Corporate Finance, Financial Engineering | 4 | 2 |
| TBD | 0 | 0 |
| Goods for Not Resale, SAP | 2 | 1 |

Comment: What result would you expect for the string `'abc def'`?

Comment: Edited the question. Below answers do not take into consideration the space delimited strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match 5 chars and on the left and right match optional chars other than a comma.

```
[^,]*[A-Za-z0-9]{5}[^,]*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/13c81i/1) with the matches.

Example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['first'])
df['first'] = [
    'Accounts Payable Goods for Resale',
    'Corporate Finance, Financial Engineering',
    'TBD',
    'Goods for Not Resale, SAP',
    'Jack Ryan, Tom O',
    'Stack Over Flow, StackOverFlow',
    'Jurassic Park, IT',
    'GOT'
]
df['countStrings'] = df['first'].str.count(r'[^,]*[A-Za-z0-9]{5}[^,]*')
print(df)
```

Output

```
                                      first  countStrings
0         Accounts Payable Goods for Resale             1
1  Corporate Finance, Financial Engineering             2
2                                       TBD             0
3                 Goods for Not Resale, SAP             1
4                          Jack Ryan, Tom O             0
5            Stack Over Flow, StackOverFlow             2
6                         Jurassic Park, IT             1
7                                       GOT             0
```

Comment: Thanks. Good solution but problem comes when there is a space between words. Edited the question to make things more informative

Comment: @LonelySoul That does not matter as you are not matching spaces right?

Comment: Thats true @thefourthbird. However, it may not work in edge cases , where, there are multiple words with length of more than 5 separated by comma

Comment: @LonelySoul So you want to match words with more than 5 chars starting with an uppercase, optionally repeated by a spaces and the same again?

Comment: @LonelySoul Why should `Goods for Not Resale, SAP` and `Accounts Payable Goods for Resale` give you 1? There are 2 words that have more than 5 characters

Comment: Not upper case but only strings where total length is more than 5 including space. Let's say we have two strings separated by comma. One is "TBD" and other is "Financial Accounting". Will count later but not TBD so total length is 1. Hope it helps

Comment: @LonelySoul Try it like this `df['countStrings'] = df['first'].str.count(r'[^,]*[A-Za-z0-9]{5,}[^,]*')`

Comment: You sir / madam are Genius

Comment: @LonelySoul I am far from that, but happy I could help :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Pandas str.len()** method is used to determine length of each string in a Pandas series. This method is only for series of strings.
Since this is a string method, .str has to be prefixed everytime before calling this method.

Yo can try this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['first'])
df['first'] = ['jack,utah,TOMHAWK 
Somer,SORITNO','jill','bob,texas','matt,AR','john']

df['first'].replace(',',' ', regex=True, inplace=True)
df['first'].str.count(r'\w+').sum()
```

Comment: Sorry I am not looking for sum of all. But a column with counts of strings having length of more than 5

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would try to get the number of strings with **len>=5** in  a column:

```
data=[i for k in df['first']
        for i in k.split(',')
        if len(i)>=5]
result=len(data)
```